# C# Linq XML Query where multiple elements of same name already exists

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My xml is like this:

```
<Destination>
        <CityCode>GRAGMRNCHN</CityCode>
        <CityName>Agia Marina</CityName>
        <ZoneCode>CRTCHN</ZoneCode>
        <ZoneName>Creta - Chania</ZoneName>
        <Departures>
          <Departure>
            <CountryCode>RO</CountryCode>
            <CountryName>Romania</CountryName>
            <CityCode>ROBCH1</CityCode>
            <CityName>Bucuresti</CityName>
            <GiataCodes>
              <GiataCode>28029</GiataCode>
              <GiataCode>759</GiataCode>
              <GiataCode>28575</GiataCode>
              <GiataCode>756</GiataCode>
              <GiataCode>47839</GiataCode>
            </GiataCodes>
            <Dates>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-06-22</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-06-29</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-07-06</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-07-13</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-07-20</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-07-27</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-08-03</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-08-10</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-08-17</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-08-24</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-08-31</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14,21">2016-09-07</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7,14">2016-09-14</Date>
              <Date TourOpCode="EU" Nights="7">2016-09-21</Date>
            </Dates>
          </Departure>
```

Now i want to extract CityCode(destination), CityCode(departure), available date and their nights attributes. I'm stack at dates! Using Xdcument i get only first elements from date.

Here is parsing code:

```
 packageList = (from destination in xDoc.Descendants(nonamespace + "Destination")
                select new PackageInformation
                {
                    DestinationCityCode = destination.Element("CityCode").Value,
                    DepartureCityCode = destination.Descendants("Departure")
                        .Select( c => new DepartureCityClass()
                        {
                            DepartureCityCode = c.Element("CityCode").Value
                        }).ToList(),
                    Dates = destination.Descendants("Departures").Descendants("Departure").Descendants("Dates")
                        .Select(d => new DatesClass()
                        {
                            Date = d.Element("Date").Value,
                            Nights = d.Element("Date").Attributes("Nights").First().Value


                        }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Any help!
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you miss _.Descendants("Date")_ after _.Descendants("Dates")_.

Comment: If I am using _.Descendants("Date")_  after _Descendants("Dates")_ then throws an error: _Object reference not set to an instance of an object_

Comment: You should use _d.Value_ and _d.Attributes("Nights")_ instead of _d.Element("Date").Value_ and _d.Element("Date").Attributes("Nights")_

Comment: I agree. Plus, in many of the cases it's not necessary to use `.Descendants()`, as this will also search all child of child of child of... elements, which decreases performance. As you're only looking at direct children anyway, use `.Element()` instead.

Comment: I got the idea. Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, should work fine:

```
var packageList = (from destination in xd.Descendants("Destination")
                        select new 
                        {
                            DestinationCityCode = destination.Element("CityCode").Value,
                            DepartureCityCode = destination.Descendants("Departure")
                                .Select(c => new 
                                {
                                    DepartureCityCode = c.Element("CityCode").Value
                                }).ToList(),
                            Dates = destination.Descendants("Departure").Descendants("Dates").Descendants("Date")
                                .Select(d => new
                               {
                                    Date = d.Value,
                                    Nights = d.Attributes("Nights").First().Value


                               }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```